# Open Excel from Java Application

Tags: java, excel, runtime

If I am tring to open notepad from Java Application then it will open Notepad.But If I will try to open Excel then it is giving me exception.

```
try
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("excel");
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Following is Exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "excel": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at OpenNotepad.main(OpenNotepad.java:18)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

When I do start->Run->Excel then it will open excel.

Comment: Use `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("path/to/spreadsheet.xls"));` from the AWT API.  If persisting with a `Process`.. Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to use Java to open an Excel file, rather than just opening Excel, I suggest you use the Desktop API class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

This class will use the default OS file handling mechanism, so it will use say MS Excel in Windows, and Open Office in Linux.

Comment: I don't have to open created Excel file i.e e.xlsx.But I have to open Microsoft Excel directly from Java Application as we can open Notepad . through Desktop API, i can not open Excel.

Answer (score 4):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("some command");` does the same as "some command" will do in cmd. So the solution for opening Excel you should try this.

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start excel.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the exec method give fuuly qualified path where your excel is installed and then try and RunTime is good but better to use ProcessBuilder

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is the same thing as doing something from the command line.

In windows OS there is an environment variable set to `C:\Windows\System32`
all the exe of commands are in this path.

when I do following in cmd I get this.

```
C:\Users\bhaviksh>echo %PATH%
D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\
System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\cvsnt;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:
\maven\bin
```

**Solution :** use fully qualified name of exe file

Answer (score 0):

Add microsoft office excel executable path
for eg: 
    If Directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14 has EXCEL.EXE then add C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14 to your classpath. 
How to add to classpath Click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).
Once you are done, restart your IDE, your program should work.